# Why getpid() is not implemented in x86_64's vdso?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, glibc, vdso

After glibc 2.25, glibc's *getpid()* wrapper no longer cache its result.
However, on x86_64 vdso didn't provide *getpid()* function.
Which means everytime *getpid()* is called, a syscall is triggered.

I am wondering why x86_64 vdso does not provide *getpid()* function (even on kernel 5.x).

Comment: Related: https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmdA5WkDNALetBn4iFeSepHjdLGJdxPBwZyY47ir1bZGAK/comp/linux/getpid_caching.html

Comment: If performance of `getpid` is that important for your application, it is likely that your application design is rather sub-optimal.